# Four consecutive positive integers <2017: smallest # is 0 mod 5, the second # is 0 mod 7, the third # is 0 mod 9, last # is 0 mod 11. What are they?

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

From this I determined that the smallest ends in 5 or 0, the second ends in 6 or 1, the third ends in 7 or 2, and the last ends in 8 or 3. I just can't seem to find the connections between them since there are so many possibilities.

Comment: Google Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: Let n be the first number.  So n= 0 mod 5, n = -1 mod 7, n= -2 mod 9 and n=-3 mod 7.  Apply Chinese remainder theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following kccu, let $x$ be the smallest. Then $2x-5$ is a multiple of 5, 7, 9 and 11, thus of their LCM, which is 3465. The size restriction means that $2x-5=3465$, so $x=1735$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ be the smallest of the numbers. Then what you are given is
\begin{align*}
x & \equiv 0 \pmod 5\\
x+1 & \equiv 0 \pmod 7\\
x+2 & \equiv 0 \pmod 9\\
x+3 & \equiv 0 \pmod {11}.
\end{align*}
Equivalently,
\begin{align*}
x & \equiv 0 \pmod 5\\
x & \equiv 6 \pmod 7\\
x & \equiv 7 \pmod 9\\
x & \equiv 8 \pmod {11}.
\end{align*}
This sort of problem can be solved using the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).